# Открытие проекта с github в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Первый раз пытаюсь работать с github. И не знаю как открыть проект, который скачал в github в Android Studio? Я сделал всё, как написано в [здесь](http://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-to-open-a-project-in-Android-Studio/)! Но проект не запустился полностью.
Ссылка на github [тут](https://github.com/SheldonNeilson/Android-Alarm-Clock)!

Answer (score 1):

Вообще там есть check out project from Version Control и далее нужно будет указать путь к git-репозиторию

Comment: `cannot run program git.exe createprocess error=2 не удается найти указанный файл `

Answer (score 0):

Установите [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/download/). После чего заново попробуйте